# Pattern Classification in a Data Frame

Tags: python, dataframe, classification

I need an classification algorithm to identify patterns based on strings in Name Column such as Patterns with "XY","F","M" in  in my dataframe.
dataframe-

```
Name    Tag         Type    Subset
XY-01   XZY-001     A       ABC
XY-01   XZY-002     B       ABC  
M-11    Y-011       A       ABC
M-11    Y-012       B       ABC
M-11    Y-013       C       ABC    
XY-13   XZY-051     A       ABC
XY-14   XZY-071     A       ABC
L-85    G-001       A       ABC
L-85    G-007       A       ABC
```

How can I do it to get the clusters of rows with "Name" containing strings as "XY", "M", "L"

I want to create a dataframe out of those clusters; for eg

```
Pattern# Instance Pattern 
1        1        XY-01   XZY-001     A       ABC 
                  XY-01   XZY-002     B       ABC 
         2        XY-13   XZY-051     A       ABC 
         3        XY-14   XZY-071     A       ABC
2        1        M-11    Y-011       A       ABC
                  M-11    Y-012       B       ABC
                  M-11    Y-013       C       ABC
3        1        L-85    G-001       A       ABC
                  L-85    G-007       A       ABC
```

Comment: Your question is very vague - what exactly are you trying to do? Once you've 'identified patterns' and 'got clusters' - what do you need to do with them?

Comment: So, you have a dataframe like this and you would like to split it in separate dataframes based on the prefix of 'Name'? Is there a reason you need it in separate dataframes, instead of just using `.groupby()`?

Comment: Please check the updated question.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Can you share code of an attempt and explain what problems you ran into? This seems fairly trivial using `groupby` and a function that grabs the prefix?

Comment: i wanted to use clustering based classification